# Does $evalAsync makes $scope.$apply unnecessary?

Tags: angularjs

From my understanding, `$evalAsync` will queue the changes to the current digest cycle if it can, if not then to the next one.

So in which cases would i use `$scope.$apply` ?

Both of them run digest on the `$rootScope`, but `$evalAsync` have the possibility to make it faster by hooking into the current digest cycle, which sounds better in 99% cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this info below link , I felt good may it will useful to you !
http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/

`$evalAsync()` is a new function which was first introduced in AngularJS 1.2.X, and in my opinion it is the adroit version of `$timeout()`.

Before `$evalAsync()` came into the picture, AngularJS team recommended using the `$timeout()` in case of digest cycle issue, described above.

As AngularJS evolved for large apps and digest cycle became common and then Angular team introduced `$evalAsync()`. This function will evaluate the expression during the current cycle or the next.

Suppose you call some expression on `$evalAsync()` and any digest cycle is going on at the same time. All expressions from `$evalAsync()` will be added to the queue and they will be part of the current lifecycle and no new digest cycle will be invoked. This is why `$evalAsync()` make it more efficient because it reduce the possibility to create new digest every time.

If there is not any digest is going on, it will work similar to $timeout. It will create a callback with default time (10 ms) and after this time (10 ms), there will be a new digest on `rootScope` and all expressions will be evaluated.

Comment: http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/ ...